# Why the frequent unexplained use of the partial modifier in EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

In the EF Code first docs and examples, you'll frequently see classes and methods defined using the `partial` modifier. [For example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx), the following

```
public partial class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public DepartmentNames Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Budget { get; set; }
}
```

I understand the general use of the `partial` keyword by the C# compiler. However, I often see these examples without applying that functionality (i.e., the class is never re-opened elsewhere).

In other examples, I have also seen `partial` modifiers on methods as well.

Do these modifiers carry some special meaning in an EF Code First context? Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: No `partial` does not have any special meaning, it is only important if the code is generated otherwise it completely unnecessary and just confuses the readers. So I would say that this is just a "copy/past error" in the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given EF makes working with POCOs really easy, this makes it flexible in terms of separating components and pieces. For example, a section that defines your models:

```
public partial class PurchaseOrder
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Double InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then apply business logic elsewhere:

```
public partial class PurchaseOrder : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And maybe extend its functionality another place still:

```
public partial class PurchaseOrder
{
    public void AddItem(PurchaseOrderItem item)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

though as @E.J. Brennan mentions, it's more likely they were generated from a T4 template. This means that anything you did in the generated file would be wiped with every generation; however, if you left the generated item alone, you could still extend it (like I've shown with `IValidatableObject` or additional methods) without worrying if your changes would be lost.

Comment: Separation of Concerns is not the same as "put this code in a different file on the file system". I think EJ Brennan's point that, if a tool is generating (and regenerating) a code, then `partial` makes sense. If the fragmentation approach you suggest works for you, more power to you, but it would give me fits.

Comment: @Mikeb: not necessarily what I practice, but showing another way you can separate things. Admittedly the furthest I've gone in terms of separation would be a POCO in one class and the `EntityTypeConfiguration<>` in another.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be unusual to use T4, or another code generator to create the basic classes that map back to your database. If one did that, you would want those classes to be partial so that you could extend those classes in a seperate file - if you extended those classes in the original file, they would get overwritten every time you re-generated the file.

If you hand coded your classes, there would be no need to use the partial on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can [extend Entity Framework generated types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456844%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The classes only contain properties that are defined in the conceptual model and do not contain any methods. The generated classes are partial.

So, in your new partial classes (not the generated ones) you can [define business logic, display attributes, validation logic etc](http://bjorn.kuiper.nu/2011/04/15/extending-your-entity-framework-classes/). These classes won't be overwritten, like the generated ones.